# Finding the equation of a sphere given two diameter endpoints

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I want to find the equation of a sphere given the endpoints of one diameter are $(4, -8, 8)$, $(6, -4, 14)$.

I know that diameter $D$ is twice the radius $r$, so $D=2r$, then any equation of a sphere that defines $r^2$ also describes the equation for $D^2/4$.

I took the distance between the points to find $D$, which gave me $D^2=56$, thus $r^2=14$ and $$(x-a)^2+(y-h)^2+(z-l)^2=14$$
for some $a, h, l \in \mathbb R$

my issue now is finding what the values of $a, h, l$ are. I've tried setting the above equation equal to the equation the same equation with $x=4, y=-8, z=8$ since both equations have the same radius -- hoping to cancel the majority of terms out, which did not happen.

Comment: center of a sphere is also the midpoint of a diameter

Comment: How do I use that then? All I have is that $r=\sqrt{14}$ which is half the diameter.  But how does that get me the midpoint?

Comment: @Lex_i For two points $(x_1, y_1, z_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2, z_2 )$ in space, the midpoint of the line they span is given by $\left(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2},  \frac{y_1+y_2}{2}, \frac{z_1+z_2}{2}\right)$.

Comment: It may be useful to work up step by step to three dimensions, rather than trying to land on it with a bang: The midpoint of two numbers $x_1$ and $x_2$ is just their average, $\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}$.  For instance, the midpoint of $5$ and $9$ is $\frac{5+9}{2} = \frac{14}{2} = 7$. ¶ The midpoint of two ordered pairs $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ is the ordered pair consisting of the midpoints of the two coordinates, $\left(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}, \frac{y_1+y_2}{2}\right)$.  For instance, the midpoint of $(2, 7)$ and $(6, 3)$ is $\left(\frac82, \frac{10}{2}\right) = (4, 5)$.

Comment: So the midpoint of two ordered triples, such as might identify two points in space, would be ...

Answer (score 1):

You are overthinking this. The numbers you are looking for are the coordinates of the center. That's the midpoint of the diameter, so easy to calculate.